# TFS2012 Wrong user missing workspaces

Tags: visual-studio-2012, migration

I have a very unusual issue with TFS2012, We've just migrated across domain and upgraded from TFS2010 to TFS2012.

All seems to work apart from one user, who we don't seem to be able to get his workspaces to work.

When I make a connection to the TFS Server, I enter the server name and port number, this connects, but in the 'Connect to Team Foundation Server' window, bottom left it shows my login credentials, even though the user logged in is categorically the user, he gets all my tfs administrator permissions.

If we connect, it shows a workspace, MB2, this workspace doesn't exist anywhere in the tfs server (used TF Sidekick to find that information as well as confirmation using tf commandline.

I think the issue is more to do with the TF connecting with my user account as all his workspaces are being labelled MB2;Paul Talbot as opposed to his user name and as such he cannot see any of these workspaces being created.

Does anyone have any idea where VS2012 is getting the user credentials from, up until this moment I had never logged onto this laptop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved it, in some bizarre circumstances (I saved credentials), my user details had been entered into Credential Manager, which caused VS2012 to connect to TFS using my account.

Comment: I am totally amazed that I managed to search up this article on the first try. Kudos for the precise problem description and accurate resolution.